# c# setting JumpList for app run from network share

Tags: c#, shell, windows-7, windows-server-2008, jump-list

I need to set the jumplist shortcuts for a c# app thats run off of 2008 server, but the machine the jumplists are be installed on are running Windows 7.

I have no issues setting jumplists when app is run locally, so I know the code works. I'm wondering if I'm missing a step or something (hopefully) obvious to others with more experience.

**Edit** [ Doesn't the app get run on the win7 machine that executes it off of the server? Could it be that I'm (unknowingly) trying to add the JumpList shortcuts to the 08 server start menu? I have just started developing for a living and I don't even know what I lack, any help is appreciated! ]

Adding "my" code in case it could help:

```
#region Win7 Specific Code
            if (m.Msg == Windows7Taskbar.TaskbarButtonCreatedMessage)
            {
                try
                {

                    jlm = new JumpListManager(appID);
                    jlm.UserRemovedItems += delegate { };

                    string strAppDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
                    app = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".exe";

                    jlm.AddUserTask(new ShellLink
                    {
                        Title = "Smart Client",
                        Path = Path.Combine(strAppDir, app),
                        Arguments = "sc",
                        IconLocation = Path.Combine(strAppDir, @"ico\a.ico")
                    });

                    jlm.AddUserTask(new ShellLink
                    {
                        Title = "Web Client",
                        Path = Path.Combine(strAppDir, app),
                        Arguments = "wc",
                        IconLocation = Path.Combine(strAppDir, @"ico\b.ico")
                    });

                    jlm.AddUserTask(new ShellLink
                    {
                        Title = "TSQL Solution",
                        Path = Path.Combine(strAppDir, app),
                        Arguments = "ts",
                        IconLocation = Path.Combine(strAppDir, @"ico\c.ico")
                    });

                    jlm.AddUserTask(new ShellLink
                    {
                        Title = "C# Solution",
                        Path = Path.Combine(strAppDir, app),
                        Arguments = "cs",
                        IconLocation = Path.Combine(strAppDir, @"ico\d.ico")
                    });

                    jlm.AddUserTask(new ShellLink
                    {
                        Title = "Report Solution",
                        Path = Path.Combine(strAppDir, app),
                        Arguments = "rs",
                        IconLocation = Path.Combine(strAppDir, @"ico\e.ico")
                    });
                    jlm.Refresh();
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance offered.

- Sam

Comment: Applications running on a network share don't get jump lists at all, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you much! I was afraid that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution was to build an application that had behavior similar to jumplists. As far as I know it is not possible to achieve my result while loading from a network share.